# Does sound travel in other dimensions?

Tags: acoustics, spacetime-dimensions

Recently I have been watching Youtube videos regarding dimensions. It wasn't clear to me whether sound travels in the other dimension (excluding 1d,2d and 3d). If so, how would it sound? If no, why?

Comment: It would take compatible ears to hear it. Mine are just 3D.

Comment: I think you need to explain more fully what you think "dimension" means and, what you think "other dimensions" means. Physical space is three-dimensional, but that does not mean that there is anything you can point to and say, "this one is the _first_ dimension, that one is the _second_ dimension, and that one over there is the _third_ dimension." That's just not what "dimension" means. What you could do instead is establish a coordinate system, and point in the directions of your three coordinate axes. But I could establish an equally valid system with three _different_ coordinate axes.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For there to be extra spatial dimensions in addition to the orthogonal three that we inhabit, those dimensions must have so little spatial extent (i.e., so "small") that they are undetectable to humans and play no role in the functioning of our everyday world. For those extra dimensions to be thus "compactified" also requires them to take the form of curves, surfaces or volumes that are twisted around themselves in such a way that they are "closed" instead of extending to infinite distances the way that width, height and depth do in 3 dimensions.

What all this means is that sound in 3 dimensions could not "leak" into those extra dimensions because they have to be smaller than the spacing between the air molecules that conduct sound waves by a ratio roughly of order (size of the observable universe/size of the earth).

And since those extra dimensions are curled up into closed shapes, something like a sound wave could not propagate from one point to another through them.

Comment: Back before precision short-range gravitation measurements ruled out the possibility of one or more large extra dimensions, I had a summer research job figuring out how vibrations in the brane where we live would couple to the bulk. The analogy we used in talks was of embedding a long metal rod (the low-dimensionality brane) in seawater (the higher-dimensional bulk), hitting the rod with a hammer, and predicting how the sound energy would leak out of the rod into the water.  But now that any extra dimensions must be compact, the problem is much less interesting.

Comment: @rob, thank you for your comments. it must have been a fascinating and exciting process to actually be a participant in events like that, rather than to just read a boiled-down version strictly for spectators on the sidelines, which nonetheless is at the limits of my comprehension as a non-physicist.

Comment: Are there any factual findings that those extra dimensions should have a very little spatial extent?

Comment: yes, if they were "large", gravity would leak into them and thereby not follow a strict 1/r^2 dependence.

Comment: Please provide some sources of such a big claim. Thank you!

Comment: Have you researched the physics of compactified dimensions?

Comment: Yes. I have read about tiny dimensions in String Theory and it's derivative theories. But these claims are yet to be proved. And I don't think answering a question with the support of an unproven hypothesis is a good practice.

Comment: Are you *at all* aware of the efforts to detect deviation from 1/r^2 gravity on short distance scales, caused by leakage of gravity into the compactified dimensions? Until you study that, you are in no position to claim the hypothesis is unproven nor that my mention of it in this context is "not good practice".

Comment: I am very much aware of the fact that there have been experiments trying to detect leakage of gravity in other dimensions thereby weakening of its force. The results suggest that there are no possible infinite extra dimensions. On the basis of this experiment, many many scholars started hypothesising that there may be compactified dimensions which don't affect the gravity and so we don't see a deviation from the inverse square law. I totally agree with experiment but my concern is with the hypothesis formed about compactified dimensions which even to this date is floating around to be proven,

Comment: Thank you bro .

Answer (score 2):

Based on the current knowledge of the scientific community, sound waves require a medium to travel. Again, based on the current knowledge of the scientific community, our materialistic world is three dimensional spatially. So sound waves travel in three dimensions until unless it's proven that we live in a universe of more than three spatial dimensions.

Answer (score -2):

Well if you take time as your 4th dimension , go to the a quiet open place like a desert with a friend , one mile away while both of you can still see each other , just scream while you jump and there you go you have the sound traveling in the 4th dimension :)